# How can we make the hotkey function of an application always working even not in foreground

Tags: windows, hotkeys

Suppose I am running an application with several hotkey functions e.g. Ctrl+1,Ctrl+2,Ctrl+3
However these hotkeys are only working when the application window is in foreground(i.e. on the top).
How can I make the hotkeys still available even when I switch to other applications?

Comment: Using which programming language/GUI toolkit/etc?  Much more information is required before anybody will be able to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call [RegisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646309.aspx), and then call [UnregisterHotKey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646327.aspx) when done.

```
RegisterHotKey(
        NULL,
        1,
        MOD_CONTROL | MOD_NOREPEAT,
        0x31);  //0x31 is '1'
```

Be sure to check for errors and handle accordingly.